# Issuer generate credential in CL signature scheme

Tags: rsa

In the paper [CL signature scheme](https://eprint.iacr.org/2001/019.pdf), the authors describe the scheme to generate and verify credentials. I have a question regarding the credential generation from issuer. In page 11, section 4.4, protocol 2 (2:2), the organizer $O$  generates a random prime $e$, and calculates $c= (P\cdot d)^{1/e}\bmod{n}$.

My question is how is $O$ able to do the calculation? Based on the strong RSA assumption, it's difficult to find $c$ and $e$ such that $c^e = P\cdot d \bmod{n}$

Comment: Doesn't $O$ know the factorisation of $n$?

Comment: Yes, O knows n=p*q. What's the efficient algorithm to do the calculation based on the factorization?

Comment: $O$ can compute $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$ and then use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to compute the inverse of $e$ modulo $\phi(n)$.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks a lot!